# Двойной ORDER BY mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть база данных с товарами.
По умолчанию товары выводятся по `id ASC`.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY id ASC
```

Есть еще поле sort_1. В нем указывается порядок сортировки, если он необходим.
Например, товар занимает по `id ASC` 5 место, а в поле `sort_1` у него указано 2 место. Он должен принужденно попасть на второе место.
В товарах поле `sort_1` может быть и пустое.

Как запрос сформулировать так, чтобы он выполнял то, что мне нужно?

Comment: В `sort_1` указано место вывода или порядок вывода?

Comment: Указано место вывода

Comment: Т.е. если поле sort_1 заполнено только у одной записи и оно равно 5, то запись должна попасть на пятую позицию? А если записей в выборке три?

Comment: Тогда значение sort_1 должно быть проигнорировано. Т.е. sort_1, фактически, должен быть приоритетнее id, если поле заполнено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас "пустое" поле означает   NULL, то как-то так:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY IFNULL(`sort_1`,`id`) ASC
```

Если же "пустое" - значит пустая строка, то что-то в этом роде:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY IF(`sort_1`<>'',`sort_1`,`id`) ASC
```